# React: Generate and save PDF onClick() problem - Kendo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, kendo-ui, telerik

What I want to achieve is to generate and save PDF file onClick(), not rendering anything in DOM.

Content should have React components HTML and CSS.

I found @progress/kendo-react-pdf package: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/pdfprocessing/

My example with bug: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-taumpw?file=index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo doesn't support rendering/saving PDF outside DOM: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-react/issues/307#issuecomment-521232445

Answer (score -1):

The first argument to savePdf is a DOM element and not a JSX element.  This will work.

```
class App extends Component {
  exportPDF() {
        // TODO: Fetch data from backend
        // TODO: Move content generator to different function
        // const element = <h2>teeeeest</h2>
        const element = document.getElementById('test')

        savePDF(element, {
            paperSize: 'A4',
            fileName: 'report.pdf',
            margin: { top: '2cm', left: '1.5cm', right: '1.5cm', bottom: '2cm' },
            scale: 0.8,
            keepTogether: '.card',
        });
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 id='hello'>Hello Kendo</h1>
        <h2 id='test' style={{display: 'none'}}>teeeest</h2>
        <NavLink className="pr-1" to="#" onClick={() => this.exportPDF()}>DOWNLOAD PDF</NavLink>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the link to the documentation for `savePdf` method - https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/pdfprocessing/api/savePDF/

Comment: Yes, but I want to generate content in separate function. And `style={{display: 'none'}}` doesn't display content in PDF

Comment: You can use document.createElement to create your html

Comment: `let element = document.createElement('div'); element.innerHTML = 'terefere<h2>hello</h2>'` not working. Please test it. I've updated my example on https://stackblitz.com